# Clone each element append next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to .Clone each a to inside the next elment which is ul

How can i do that ?

```
<ul>

<li>
<a>link<a>
<ul></ul>
<li>

<li>
<a>link<a>
<ul></ul>
<li>

<li>
<a>link<a>
<ul></ul>
<li>

<li>
<a>link<a>
<ul></ul>
<li>

</ul>
```

I have tried:

```
$("a").each(function () {
    $(this).clone().insertAfter(this).find('ul');
});
```

The problem is i get the new cloned elment just beside the original one, i wish to insert it inside the next ul elment

thanks

Comment: Your HTML is invalid it makes very little sense. `<li><a>link</a></li>` should be inside `<ul>...</ul>`.

Comment: That's right, but that's comes with "Max mega menu WP plugin"

Comment: That's awful my sympathies. If the plugin allows you to create valid HTML dynamically, you might want to wrap the cloned link in a `<li>`, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55272479/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the `next` list, then `append` the `clone`d element. I also fixed your invalid HTML:

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).next("ul").append($(this).clone(true));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>link</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>link</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>link</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>link</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid HTML requires that `<ul>` can only have `<li>` as a direct descendant (child). A `<li>` can have anything within itself, but it needs to end properly with a `</li>`. The demo follows the following pattern:

> ```
>    <ul><!------------------------------Main List-->
>      <li><!----------------------------List Item-->
>        <a href='#/'>LINK 1</a><!---Original Link-->
>        <ul><!------------------------Target List-->
>          <li><!--------------------New List Item-->
>            <a href='#/'>LINK 1</a><!--Clone Link-->
>          </li>
>        </ul>
>       </li>
>      ...
>    </ul>
> ```

---

### Demo

```js
/*
.each() <a>
Create a .clone() of current <a>
Find .next() <ul>
.append() the clone to <ul>
.wrapInner() of <ul> with a <li>
*/
$("a").each(function() {
  var dupe = $(this).clone(true, true);
  $(this).next('ul').append(dupe).wrapInner(`<li></li>`);
});
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>
    <a href='#/'>LINK 1</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href='#/'>LINK 2</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href='#/'>LINK 3</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href='#/'>LINK 4</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```